# Connecting my MySQL databases to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am running Mac OS 10.10.2. I have recently been educating myself about php and SQL in order to create an online database application for my employer. However, I have been unable to load up my MySQL databases in phpMyAdmin. I have tried following some advice from this forum, but no answers seem to solve my issue.

I installed MySQLWorkbench (Ver. 6.2.4.12437) as well as XAMPP (Ver. 5.6.3-0), and was using phpMyAdmin to have a play around and better understand what I was getting myself into. I then found one of those follow-the-bouncing-ball type teaching websites which advised me to download and install the MySQL community server (Currently running Ver. 5.6.23)

As instructed, I was learning SQL commands through Terminal and built up some databases/tables this way. I decided I wanted to jump into phpMyAdmin where I felt it'd be easier to continue my work. At first XAMPP was unable to turn on the servers which I overcame by uninstalling and reinstalling. Then I was getting a #2002 error when trying to access phpMyAdmin. I tinkered with config files and put in details relating to my localhost MySQL server (Or at least I assume as much).

I was able to get back into phpMyAdmin finally, but my databases made through terminal are not there.

**phpMyAdmin shows:** cdcol (the example database), information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, phpmyadmin, and test.

**If I open terminal and punch in 'mysql' then 'SHOW DATABASES;' it only lists:** information_schema.

**If I open terminal and punch in 'mysql' with username 'root' and my password, then 'SHOW DATABASES;' it lists:** information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, my tutorial/learning database, and my business database. I dropped the test database from here. *THESE are what I want to bring up in phpMyAdmin.*

I can only guess that I haven't got it configured properly to access this last mysql server, but I can't determine where I am going wrong. If anyone can shed some light on this, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you have two MySQL installations -- the one that comes with XAMPP and the MySQL Community Server that you installed? Or did you completely remove one of them? It sounds like you have two server instances, which explains why you can't see the databases from one in the other.

Comment: I believe that must be the case. Does XAMPP always have its own MySQL installation running, or can I deactivate/uninstall it and tell XAMPP to use the MySQL Community Server instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you have two MySQL instances; one from the XAMPP and also the MySQL Community Server that you installed yourself.

The "M" of XAMPP is for MySQL, so yes usually it runs its own MySQL server instance. That's sort of the point of the packaged kit, so you don't have to worry about having any of your own applications installed. In theory it should be no problem to stop the XAMPP MySQL instance and instead use your other one, but may require tweaking some configuration files and is probably not supported. If you can make it work, I don't see a reason why it would be a problem, though.

My suggestion is to either use the complete XAMPP stack or roll your own installation rather than mix and match.